# Is it possible to commiunicate with jboss/keycloak:16.1.1using REST APIs?

Tags: rest, jboss, keycloak

I am requeired to commiunicate with `jboss/keycloak:16.1.1` via REST APIs, but ***i am not sure if this version of keyloak really supports REST APIs*** !!!

Here is what i have done:

1. Run the below command to get a running docker container in port 8080 of your machine:

   `docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin jboss/keycloak:16.1.1`
2. Open the http://localhost:8080/  and login as admin/admin
3. Create a new client called `admin-rest-client`
4. Setup the authentication configuration as below so that i can get the ***client's secret***:
   [image]
5. Save the client

Now i should be able to get the Token by calling `GET http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token`

and here is what i have tried with postman:

[image]

As you see, sadly the response is `404`, so i am wondering if REST APIs is supported with `jboss/keycloak:16.1.1` ?

---

I have already successfully commiunicate via REST with `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0` but my here my question is about `jboss/keycloak:16.1.1` !!! This docker image is relatively old and the latest images goes back to two years ago!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old versions (under v18 legacy) have extra URL 'auth'

```
POST http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

New versions (higher v18)

```
POST http://localhost:8080/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

[image]

If click here (red box) get the Token URL

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is great. Do you know, how can i find the other REST APIs to create (or GET) users ?

Sadly, the below documentation does not work:
https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/21.0.1/rest-api/index.html#_userrepresentation

Comment: @Jeff, OLD REST API documentation no more support from Keycloak team.
But most REST API is same between v16 and v23. You just add "/auth" path. If you want to know more detail, make new question. I will review it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please find my new question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77705233/is-it-possible-to-create-new-user-with-jboss-keycloak16-1-1using-rest-apis

Comment: @Jeff, I answered your question.