# Is it possible to create new user with jboss/keycloak:16.1.1using REST APIs?

Tags: rest, jboss, keycloak

[Based on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77704804/is-it-possible-to-commiunicate-with-jboss-keycloak16-1-1using-rest-apis/77704985#77704985),I am able to successfully:

1. Run a docker container based on `jboss/keycloak:16.1.1`
2. Setup a client which has secret and client_id
3. Get a valid access_token

However, i am requeired *to create (and GET)* **users** in *keycloak* via REST APIs. In the below picture, you can see what i have tried in postman and as a result i got `404`:

[image]

***Question1:*** Is create and GET users via REST supported in `jboss/keycloak:16.1.1` ?

When i check the provided APIs in the below picture, there is no API related to users.

[image]

***Question2: Which roles do i need to assign to my client to be able to create or get users ?***

I use the jwt website to investigate my token and i figured out this token has a few `realm_roles` and `accoint_roles` such as  `[ "default-roles-master", "offline_access", "uma_authorization" ]` , but i am not sure if these are roles which give me the previledegs to create or get user. Are they ?

Here is my token, and you can put it in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) and check the results:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJ2X1gtMFJaTWhEbkNER0NnUjhoZGx5RGRwaENvUWxOcnNuZHZVUm9scms4In0.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.LuEEDoRKubMXrccgxAkpVPun4jbmr7Kn_8EG0eeyxcwudnEF-aUDd0zLEIz8cDUnvLybbAIfq0CUOr6sslTdzgV52FFrOrIfo3kqyy6stHEuhSCs-G7SPwwbv3aOIUmQqC9H2Mi4rW3K46edutBGwDKqJ-bSKTTHfhw128UrU-x5Clk7pZ1hHEV56KttgBtlLIOpmhQ4Ji88ah0RaYb3I9j7ekLQWwUmd04c1JfR3rcOEquYYUfA-Se2wyhDP14HNOCQWq4Nx1ctf3Y9KDfX_qqF-cjG7JJy88bc7FDjBZjC5xAfdahScLS3aUR_wa0NyBYEY-4BC1G3qHMkvPYycg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### #1   Create User and Get users by REST API

1. Assign "manage_users" role to client
   [image]
2. Get Token
   [image]

[image]

Decoding token by [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/)
[image]

3. Create User

```
POST http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/my-realm/users
```

In Body

```
{
  "enabled": true,
  "attributes": {},
  "groups": [],
  "username": "user2",
  "emailVerified": "",
  "email": "user2@test.com",
  "firstName": "Tom",
  "lastName": "Cruise"
}
```

[image]

[image]

Result
[image]

#### #2 Which role to create a user in the client

"manage-users" role.

Detail in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74873837/keycloak-using-curl-api-to-create-a-keycloak-client-with-the-view-users-role/74881364#74881364) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73606410/which-api-should-use-to-get-user-permissions-list-by-userid-with-keycloak-admin/73607156#73607156)

Comment: This is wonderful. How may i contact you if i have any further questions ?
Do you have a linkedin account ?

Comment: Sure, leave your linked in account, I will contact you.